# Office.js How to apply a character style to selected word

Tags: javascript, office-js

Apologies - new to Javascript and Office.js  But it's time to convert my .NET formatting ribbons over to be cross platform.  A bit of a learning curve.

I use this function that I found the Addin tutorial, to successfully apply a paragraph style, but I've tried tweaking it (see below) and they while I have learned that it's important to completely shut down the addin, exit out of word and go back in and reload before testing changes (very tedious), it still applies to character style to the entire paragraph. Grr

```
function applyemphasisstyle() {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var pars = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
        pars.load();
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < pars.items.length; i++) {
                pars.items[i].style = "Emphasis";

            }

        return context.sync();
    })
    }) //needed for Stack overflow
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried changing:

```
var pars = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
```

to

```
var pars = context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges;
```

I've tried just removing ".paragraphs"
I've tried changing ".paragraphs" to ".words" etc
same result - applies the style, but the entire paragraph, not the selected word.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. Since you are selecting a single word, there's nothing to loop through and since you are writing to the style property, instead of reading it, there's no need to load the text object.

```
return Word.run(function(context) {
  var selectedText = context.document.getSelection();
   return context.sync()
   .then(function () {
     selectedText.style = "Emphasis";
   })
});
```

I recommend that you use the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?tab=Overview) tool to work out the logic of your script.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the suggested answer, somehow this didn't work for me - it still applied the character style to the entire paragraph instead of the selected word.
I assumed I needed to precede your code with the function call "function applyemphasisstyle() { and ended the code lines with a closing bracket.  
What could be causing the code to work for you and not in my environment?  The mysteries of JavaScript...

Comment: PS I will take a look at Script Lab - thanks for the tip

Comment: Hi Rick - I've just looked at this again and it does work. Apologies.  I must have mis-typed something.  Apologies for taking so long to get back, but doing this dev around other work. Yay!  Thanks.